# How to set navigation controller settings only one time

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

In my swift app I've many navigation controller and for each of them I want to set this settings:

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backArrow").withRenderingMode(.automatic)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "backArrow")
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 235/255, blue: 235/255, alpha: 1)
```

How can I set this settings only one time, I mean without write this code for each class?

Comment: Just create a BaseViewController class as a parent class of all your viewController and write all setting in BaseViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Create a BaseViewController like

```
class BaseViewConroller: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navSetting()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func navSetting() {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backArrow").withRenderingMode(.automatic)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "backArrow")
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: 
.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 235/255, blue: 235/255, alpha: 1)
   }
}
```

You can create all your view controller like

```
class HomeViewController: BaseViewConroller {
   ...
}
```